# Why does Mathematica sets ListPlot x-axis as a number of points rather than the actual values?

Tags: plotting

I have this code:

```
AllData= Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/DsVfiMZN", "Table"];
data1=AllData[[All,1;2]];
ListLinePlot[data1,PlotRange->All]
```

Which generates:
[image]

My question is why does Mathematica set the x-axis as the number of points in the data rather than the actual values? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Perhaps you can explain the structure of the data in AllData in more detail?

Comment: Did you just forget a ";" [[All, 1;;2]]?

Comment: AllData is a set of 19 pairs (x,y) values (1000 lines for each pair) for which I selected only the first (x,y) in data1. The graph is correct, but rather than plotting the x-axis as something from 0 to 7, it showed as 0 to 1000, which is the number of points.

Comment: @Rodrigo if you view the `data1` you defined you'll find it isn't a set of 1000 pairs but just 1000 numbers. FredrikD's suggestion fixes this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a missing ";" in the Part[] expression that selects the pairs from AllData

```
 AllData= Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/DsVfiMZN", "Table"];
    data1=AllData[[All,1;;2]];
    ListLinePlot[data1,PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes... the extra ";" :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange) for this purpose. For example:

```
data = Sin[Subdivide[0, 2Pi, 100]];
```

Without [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange):

```
ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

With [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange):

```
ListPlot[data, DataRange->{0, 2Pi}]
```

[image]

An alternative is to use a list of pairs instead, e.g.:

```
ListPlot @ Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, Subdivide[0, 2Pi, 100]}]
```

> same picture as before